# jQuery SELECT input change option selected when clicking button up or down

Tags: html, jquery, spinner, html-select

```
<select id="edit-attributes-1">
      <option value="44" selected="selected">0</option>
      <option value="35">1</option>
      <option value="36">2</option>
      <option value="37">3</option>
</select>
<select id="edit-attributes-2">
      <option value="44" selected="selected">0</option>
      <option value="35">1</option>
      <option value="36">2</option>
      <option value="37">3</option>
</select>
<select id="edit-attributes-3">
      <option value="44" selected="selected">0</option>
      <option value="35">1</option>
      <option value="36">2</option>
      <option value="37">3</option>
</select>
<select id="edit-attributes-4">
      <option value="44" selected="selected">0</option>
      <option value="35">1</option>
      <option value="36">2</option>
      <option value="37">3</option>

</select>
    <select id="edit-attributes-9" name="attributes[9]" class="form-select">
      <option value="44" selected="selected">0</option>
      <option value="35">1</option>
      <option value="36">2</option>
      <option value="37">3</option>
    </select>

       <select id="edit-attributes-11" name="attributes[11]" class="form-select">
      <option value="45" selected="selected">0</option>
      <option value="39">1</option>
      <option value="41">2</option>

    </select>
```

​

```
//This Code adds <span>+</span> and <span>-</span> with their attributes
$('select[id^="edit-attributes-"][id!="edit-attributes-12"]').after(function() {
    var count = $(this).find('option').length;
    return '<span class="step stepup step-' + this.id + '" id="step-up-' + this.id.substring(16) + '">+</span><span class="step stepdown step-' + this.id + '" id="step-down-' + this.id.substring(16) + '">-</span>';

});

//This code detects reacts when + or - is clicked.
$('span[id^="step-"]').click(function() {
    //Tokenized class name into array <span class="step stepup step-edit-attributes-1" id="step-up-1">+</span> 
    var classList = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/); 
    //Use for Option Index = 0 ofcourse
    var min = 0;
    //Use for Option Index Max = number of options in particular Select
    var max = $("#" + classList[2].substring(5) + " option").length;
    //Index of selected Option
    var selected = $("#" + classList[2].substring(5) + " option:selected").index();
    //Value of Selected Option
    var value = $("#" + classList[2].substring(5) + " option:selected").val();

    //since id is "step-up-ID" just want to get the UP or DOWN
    var op = this.id.split("-");


    if (op[1] == "up") { // second token of op = up or down

        if (value < max) {
            value++;
            alert(selected + ":" + value + " : " + op[1]);            
            //remove any selected option ??????
//MY PROBLEM IS HERE WHEN I TRY TO REMOVE EXISTING SELECTED AND SELECT A NEW OPTION AFTER THE SELECTED ONE**

            $("#" + classList[2].substring(5) + " option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
            //assign new selected option ???????
            $("#" + classList[2].substring(5) + " option").selectedIndex=value;
        }
    }
    if (op[1] == "down") {
        if (value > min) {            
            value--;
            alert(selected + ":" + value + " : " + op[1]);
//MY PROBLEM IS HERE WHEN I TRY TO REMOVE EXISTING SELECTED AND SELECT A NEW OPTION BEFORE THE SELECTED ONE**
            $("#" + classList[2].substring(5) + " option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
            $("#" + classList[2].substring(5) + " option").selectedIndex=value;
        }

    }
});​
```

My goal is here when I click (`-`) it will change selected 1 step above, then (`+`) select new option one stop below. Can someone help out and maybe optimized this code. I've been trying to swim on this for hours already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working version + optimised of your script.

```
//This code detects reacts when + or - is clicked.
$('span[id^="step-"]').click(function() {
    //Tokenized class name into array <span class="step stepup step-edit-attributes-1" id="step-up-1">+</span> 
    var classList = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/),
        item      = $('#'+classList[2].substring(5)),
        selected  = item[0].selectedIndex;

    //since id is "step-up-ID" just want to get the UP or DOWN
    var op = this.id.split("-");

    var index = (op[1] == 'up' ? 1 : -1) + selected;
    if (item.find('option')[index]) {
        item[0].selectedIndex = index;
    }    
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rezigned/qjVHM/15/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qjVHM/14/ <-- wow, i updated and my code looks way too noob from your codes.. thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

You are dynamically generating the HTML for `+` and `-` right? Then you should use `on` instead of `click`:

http://api.jquery.com/on/

---

Do the `selects` have a common parent `div`?

If so then change your code to something like:

```
$("#parentDiv").on("click", 'span[id^="step-"]', function() {....});
```

Comment: the generation of + is already taken care of,  but click when the gnerated + is clicked... I'm sorry i don't how on works to click event, can you tweak my code instead so i can understand well..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qjVHM/12/ <-- i have created this, seems to work now with my select option, though when i press +++ it rotates from zero 0 1 2 3 then goes back to zero while it should stuck to 3 even if i click more..

Answer (score 0):

Try Delegating the event to a prentStatic container of the span..

```
$(document).on('click','span[id^="step-"]',function() {
```

If you have any static container that encloses this other than the document then you can use that container..